# Map method skipped when processing Gzip files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am working with Mapreduce to process Xml files. I have written Custom Input Format by following the code in http://thinkbigdataanalytics.com/xmlinputformat-hadoop/. When I run the job, it succeeds for XML Files. But when I run the same code for gzip files containing Xmls, the map method is not even invoked.

It says,

```
Map-Reduce Framework

Map input records=0
```

I have a few Loggers inside map() and they are not showing up too. Please suggest a solution!

Comment: And the extension of these files are?

Comment: Sample file - IND_9500_001.xml.gz   If I decompress it to IND_9500_001.xml, it is working fine.

Comment: And these files are immediately inside the input path given to the job?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was to get the file codec and use the appropriate compression codec using the `CompressionCodecFactory` Class. Please Refer http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=Cloud9/src/dist/edu/umd/cloud9/collection/XMLInputFormat.java

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo for the suggestions

Comment: Ha ha...I thought of adding it as an answer and deleted the comment. Good you implemented it.